# Добавление числовых значений в колонку с другой колонки

Tags: python, pandas

Не знаю, как добавить значения из 2 столбца в первый столбец в одной строке, только если там пусто. На фотографии исходный датафрейм, нужно заполнить левую колонку значениями с правой
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxH0E.png

```
print(df_left_merge.apply(lambda x: [x["Факт РК Д2022"], (x["Факт РК Я2023"]+x['Факт РК Д2022'])] if x['Факт РК Д2022'] not in x["Факт РК Я2023"] else [x['Факт РК Д2022'], x["Факт РК Я2023"]], axis =1, result_type='broadcast'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут лучше использовать метод `fillna()`, а не `apply()`, так как мы заполняем пропуски. По вопросу не совсем понятны названия столбцов и таблицы, но решение в общем виде примерно такое:

```
df['столбец_с_пропусками'] = df['столбец_с_пропусками'].fillna(df['столбец_без_пропусков'])
```